# Ajax ActionLink creating a GET instead of POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create an Ajax POST link which sends a Model.Id to a Controller:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Reply", "Reply", new { MessageId = m.Id },
        new AjaxOptions() {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "send",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        })
```

This is generating the following HTML in the browser:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#send" href="/Messages/Reply?MessageId=12">Reply</a>
```

To be complete, here's the code from the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reply(int MessageId) {
        var MV = new MessageViewModel {
            ToUser = db.Users.Find(MessageId).Name,
        };

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            return PartialView("_SendMessagePartial", MV);
        } else {
            return View("Index", GetCurrentMessages());
        }
    }
```

Yet it is still performing a GET request. I'm working with MVC4, and both **jQuery v1.9.1** and **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** are loaded in the correct order. I don't get any Javascript errors either. I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong. How can i get this POST request to work?

Comment: "Yet it is still performing a GET request".  What do you mean by this? What is the actual result?

Comment: You don't need a POST request, remove the [HttpPost] annotation and you will see the correct id in the Reply Action